# replacing most recent line in jupyter matplotlib chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

I'm using matplotlib to generate a chart with a dynamic line at any point on the y-axis as a threshold (that is, the user clicks on the chart somewhere and a new line will be generated that replaces the previous one).  I can add new lines with `axhline()`, but I can't figure out how to remove the previous line.  I've seen references to `Artist.remove` and `ax.remove.line(0)`, but I'm still fairly new to matplotlib and haven't been able to get anything to work.

NB:  I've only been working in Jupyter, so I don't know if this will work as-is outside of Jupyter.  Also, I know that the separate `update()` procedure isn't really necessary here, but I'll most likely need it for future functionality.

```py
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.figure as fig
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.axes import Axes as ax
from matplotlib.artist import Artist as art

x = np.random.normal(size = 1000)
plt.hist(x, bins=50, alpha=0.75)
plt.gcf().canvas.draw()
green = plt.axhline(35, color='g')
print('green line = {}'.format(green))

def update(threshold, lines):
    plt.gca().set_title('most recent line = {}'.format(lines))

def on_press(event):
    threshold = event.ydata
    lines = plt.axhline(threshold, color='r')
    update(threshold, lines)

plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', on_press)
```

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer -- might be cleaner than editing the Q. It's okay to answer your own question.

Comment: Done, thanks.  I wasn't sure what the right thing to do was in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best way to do it or I just got lucky, but I found that calling `plt.delaxes()` before drawing the new line got me what I needed. The `axhline()` is the last thing I draw on the plot before the user has a chance to interact with it, so that may be why it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can get at the lines in the subplot with `plt.gca().lines`, so you can just add something like this to the beginning of your `on_press()` function:

```
plt.gca().lines.pop()
```

Or adding `plt.gca().pop(0)` to the `update()` function also seems to work.

Comment: I couldn't get either of those to work for me, the old lines didn't get removed.  `plt.delaxes()` did what I needed in this case, so I'm good.